# How can I instantantiate an object of a class created in other file?

Tags: javascript, constructor, instantiation

Hi I'm new at javascript and I can't instantiate an object of another class, I have summarize it in a simple example. When I run foo.js I got the following error:

`let j = new Test(3)`
`TypeError: Test is not a constructor`

Test.js:

```
class Test{
    constructor(k){
        this.myAttribute = k
    }
    print(){
        console.log("This is my attribute " + k)
    }
}
```

Foo.js:

```
'use strict'

const Test = require('./test.js')

let j = new Test(3)
j.print()
```

What am I doing wrong? This is so simple and I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Is that NodeJS? If yes, add `module.exports = Test;` to the first file.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class Test{
    constructor(k){
        this.myAttribute = k
    }
    print(){
        console.log("This is my attribute " + k)
    }
}
```

then

```
import { Test } from './test'

let j = new Test(3)
j.print()
```

Here is a StackBlitz demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wvrdlj?file=index.js

Had to mod your test class to log myAttribute as k is undefined in the print method

Comment: print should use this.myAttribute